# Is it always true that $A+(X\cap Y)=(A+X)\cap (A+Y)$ if $A,X,Y$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

By $X+Y$, I mean the vector subspace $X+Y=\{x+y$ $|$ $x\in X$ and $y\in Y\}$.

I think I can prove that  $A+(X\cap Y) \subseteq (A+X) \cap (A+Y)$ but I'm not sure if the converse is true and I can't seem to find an obvious counterexample.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider $A,X,Y$ three pairwise different 1-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Answer (score 2):

Consider $X=\{a(0,1)\mid a\in \mathbb{R}\}$, $Y=\{a(1,0)\mid a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $A=\{a(1,1)\mid a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ all of them being subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $(A+X)\cap (A+Y)$ = $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $A+ (X\cap Y)$=$A$.